# Python XLWT - Issue with custom format

Tags: python, excel, datetime, xlwt

I am trying to put time into a cell. I need it to be independent without the year, month, day data datetime appends.
When I try writing a string **15:55:00** with format **h:mm AM/PM** it shows up as **15:55:00** on the excel sheet until I select the cell and press enter, so it seems that this isn't a valid way to do it.

Passing datetime works but again, I do not want to have date information in my cell, just properly formatted time.

My current code is as follows:

```
style = XFStyle()
style.num_format_str = 'h:mm:ss AM/PM'
time = "15:22:00"
ws.write(i, 4, time, style)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no such thing in Excel as a time without a date.  The value of a cell can be formatted so that the date portion doesn't show up, but it's still stored in the cell no matter what.

When you enter a time manually into Excel, it assumes a date of zero (which Excel will happily display as January 0, 1900 given the proper formatting).  If this is what you want to replicate using `xlwt`, then simply use a Python `datetime.time` object instead of a `datetime.datetime`:

```
import datetime

style = XFStyle()
style.num_format_str = 'h:mm:ss AM/PM'
time = datetime.time(hour=15, minute=22, second=0)
ws.write(i, 4, time, style)
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked. I have separated pieces of time in the string into hours, minutes and seconds and got a desired result. I am sure there's a more elegant solution for what I'm trying to achieve but this works. Thanks.

Comment: @IL3DSM: If you are OK with having a nonzero date portion (honestly, I don't see why not), then use `datetime.datetime` objects, which can be generated from strings with the `strptime` method. Also, depending on how you're grabbing the pieces from your string, it might be easier to use the `time.strptime` method (this doesn't give you a `datetime.time` object, but rather a named tuple).